# Get Instagram max_tag_id value using the instagram endpoint for pagination

Tags: api, tags

I'm fetching the Instagram feeds using the tag with some filters. I've successfully fetched the Instagram images from the API. I'm working on the filtering of the images by removing the images that have bad words in the image caption. The filter is working fine but the problem is where I've to use the max_tag_id. As per my filters, the images might get removed from the feeds due to which the number of the images that is required for me might not appear in the first call of the API call. Now the problem I'm facing is gettings the value of the max_tag_id from where the last image appeared in my feed. So that in the next pagination I can use that max_tag_id value to fetch another set of images.

I'm trying to find the way to set the value of the max_tag_id manually from the last image that appeared in the filtered array but looks like Instagram returns the max_tag_id as hashed values. Can anyone know how to get the value of the max_tag_id for the last fetched image so that the next set of images will continue from the last image that gets fetched previously?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @NeilNand No i haven't found any solution yet. I'll post it here if i found any solution :)